# Using if Statement In PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

ok i want to execute this query in PHPMyAdmin

```
update dle_post set full_story =concat(full_story ,"[H1]My List[/H1]
[RL1]") where category="283"
```

but want to add some thing like
if " )" in full_story or in short_story then this will execute
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this condition -

```
...
WHERE
  category="283"
  AND (LOCATE(' )', full_story) > 0 OR LOCATE(' )', short_story ) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` this ?

```
UPDATE dle_post 
SET full_story = CONCAT(full_story ,"[H1]My List[/H1] [RL1]") 
WHERE category = "283" AND 
(full_story LIKE '%)%' OR short_story LIKE '%)%')
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'in short_story LIKE '% )%')' at line 4

Comment: looks like it was cut and pasted from the original question... have corrected.